# Can't select Range

Tags: vba, excel

I'm creating a VBA macro to pull a filtered range of data into a template. I keep getting the Range not Defined error.

I've tried using the Macro Recording tool in Excel but when I try and use it with my written code, it breaks instantly.

```
'filter to correct range
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$X$1647").AutoFilter Field:=14, Criteria1:="-333"
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$X$1647").AutoFilter Field:=17, Criteria1:= _
    "rslicenceHolder"

'Copy Results and Paste into Template
Range("A1082:T1082").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
Active.Workbook("Sample Chasers Template .xlsx").Activate
Sheets("RS Chasers").Select
Range("A4").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Comment: what's your goal? do you want to copy/paste all filtered values or only filtered values in a certain row range?

Comment: First of all, rather than using ".Select" everywhere, use variables to build and store these ranges. Using select is a problem because if you click anywhere in Excel while the code is running, it throws everything off because you're changing the current selection.

Comment: Second, what is "Active.Workbook"? It should be "ActiveWorkbook".

Comment: User3598756, I want to copy the filtered data from rows A to T into a template with the headings already in, so I don't want the headings from the sheet I'm copying from.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

The code below will copy the Filtered table from your sheet to "RS Chasers" sheet in "Sample Chasers Template .xlsx" workbook.

**Note**: try to avoid using `ActiveSheet`, `Select` and `Selection` and use fully qualified objects instead.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyFilterData()

Dim Rng As Range, VisRng As Range

With Worksheets("Sheet1") '<-- modify "Sheet1" to your sheet's name
    Set Rng = .Range("$A$1:$X$1647") ' <-- better use referenced sheet than ActiveSheet

    Rng.AutoFilter Field:=14, Criteria1:="-333"
    Rng.AutoFilter Field:=17, Criteria1:="rslicenceHolder"

    Set VisRng = Rng.Resize(Rng.Columns(17).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count, 20).Offset(1, 0) '<-- set visible Range to filtered range

    VisRng.Copy Destination:=Workbooks("Chasers Template.xlsx").Worksheets("RS Chasers").Range("A4")   '<-- copy >> paste in 1 line
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! This works like a charm, must always remember to use Dim's for ranges.

Answer (score 0):

Your reference to the workbook "Sample Chasers Template .xlsx" is incorrect.  Try this:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$X$1647").AutoFilter Field:=14, Criteria1:="-333"
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$X$1647").AutoFilter Field:=17, Criteria1:= _
    "rslicenceHolder"

'Copy Results and Paste into Template
Range("A1082:T1082").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
'Active.Workbook(Sample Chasers Template .xlsx").Activate
Workbooks("Sample Chasers Template .xlsx").Activate

Sheets("RS Chasers").Select
Range("A4").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

I should mention though that you'll still be copying and pasting A1082:T1082 and down, regardless of where your filtered results actually are.  You may also want to substitute that piece for something like:

```
Range("A1:T1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
```

Answer (score 0):

**edited** to include actual workbook names as specified by OP

assuming you want to copy/paste all columns A to T filtered cells excluding headers:

```
Dim repWB as Workbook, tempWb as Workbook 

Set tempWb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Desktop\Template.xlsx") '<--| change "C:\Desktop\" to actual path of template workbook
Set repWB = Workbooks.Open("C:\Desktop\Report.xlsx") '<--| change "C:\Desktop\" to actual path of report workbook
With repWB.Range("$A$1:$X$1647")
    .AutoFilter Field:=14, Criteria1:="-333"
    .AutoFilter Field:=17, Criteria1:="rslicenceHolder"
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells) > 1 Then .Resize(.Rows.count - 1, 20).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy             tempWb.Sheets("RS Chasers").Range("A4")
    .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
End With
```

Comment: That works great, but now I'm getting error 9 Subscript out of range, but it is copying it and progress is always good. At the moment I've got both workbooks as the following: Dim wkb as Workbook and Dim tmp as Workbook

Comment: Set tmp = Workbooks.Open(Template.xlsx) and Set wkb = Workbooks.Open(Report.xlsx)

Comment: You need to include the full path and quotation marks e.g. `Set tmp = Workbooks.Open("C:\Desktop\Template.xlsx")`

Comment: @bagleyboy, see edited answer to match your actual workbooks names. You just need to change their paths (currently "C\Desktop\") to their actual ones. If this solved your question please mark answer as accepted thank you.